SQL Incorporate rows while rollup
I have a View in SQL Server Express that shows total values rolled up per Date
Below is how the view is currently built
SELECT        
    COALESCE(MACH, 'Total') AS MACH,
    COALESCE(DATE, '')  AS 'DATE',
    SUM(VAL) AS VAL
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY 
    ROLLUP (MACH, DATE)
HAVING
    (MACH IS NULL) OR (DATE <> '')

Inside myTable I have these events:
| MACH | DATE       | TIME     | VAL |
| 1    | 02/05/2024 | 17:35:17 | 100 |
| 1    | 02/05/2024 | 19:35:17 | 100 |
| 2    | 02/05/2024 | 21:35:17 | 100 |
| 1    | 03/05/2024 | 04:35:17 | 100 |
| 2    | 03/05/2024 | 05:35:17 | 100 |
| 1    | 03/05/2024 | 07:35:17 | 100 |

and my View is like this:
| MACH  | DATE       | VAL |
| 1     | 02/05/2024 | 200 |
| 1     | 03/05/2024 | 200 |
| 2     | 02/05/2024 | 100 |
| 2     | 03/05/2024 | 100 |
| Total |            | 600 |

What I want to do is incorporate two dates into one when myTable.TIME is before 06:00 AM.
The view should then looks like below:
| MACH  | DATE       | VAL |
| 1     | 02/05/2024 | 300 |
| 1     | 03/05/2024 | 100 |
| 2     | 02/05/2024 | 200 |
| Total |            | 600 |

Is it possible?
I tried using CASE WHEN inside ROLLUP but had no luck and I can't figure out how to do it

I’m sorry, I can’t really make sense of your desired output. Your group by already sums by date regardless of time?

Yes but what I want to do is having rows with time before 6.00 to result as if they were in the day before

Ah, I see, sorry. rollup (MACH, iif(TIME < '06:00', DATE-1, DATE)) should work? Not sure about the time notation.

(MACH IS NULL) OR (DATE <> '') shouldn't that be in the WHERE? There's no aggregation in any of those clauses.

@ThomA it’s to remove the subtotals.

Then maybe you want GROUPING SETS, not ROLLUP.

@BenderBoy Sorry my question wasn't very clear. I tried your solution but i get this error message: "Column 'DATE' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

@Dume yeah, you have to put the iif into the select and in the having, it’s kind of annoying. Check out my answer below for a full solution. I think it’s what you’re after. Cheers

@ThomA you're right, grouping sets is better here. I used roll-up because my initial idea was to have a row to separate every group but I changed my mind because I don't want to see subtotals. Do you know of a way to replace subtotals with Null?

Sou ds like you might have a new question, @Dume . Don't forget to provide sample data, and expected results, in a consumable format, along with your attempts when you ask.

Here I moved the relevant calculation into a subquery, so you don’t have to repeat it three times. As you can see, it’s just “if the time is before 06:00, use the day before”:
select
    coalesce(MACH, 'Total') AS MACH,
    RollupDate AS 'DATE',
    sum(VAL) AS VAL
from
    (select *, iif(TIME < '06:00', dateadd(day, -1, DATE), DATE) as RollupDate
    from ##MyTable) X
group by
    rollup (MACH, RollupDate)
having
    RollupDate is not null


I think, It is better to have an internal select that concatnate Date and Time and convert it to DateTime,
Then subtract 6 hours from the result,
It means you calculate your day from 6 morning to next day's 6 morning.
I hope it can be resolve your issue.
